# How to display Data from DataBase in tkinter in the labels?

Tags: python, tkinter

here is my code how can I display the Data in the labels in tkinter Thanks in advance

```py
def fetch_data():
    con = pymysql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", password = "", database = "senior_project")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from user")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
    
    output=''
    for row in rows:
        output=output+row[0]+' '+row[1]+'\n'
        return output

    full_name = StringVar()
    gender = StringVar()
    birthdate = pymysql.DATE()
    idetification = IntVar()
    phone = StringVar()
    HealthStatus = StringVar()
    
username_label = Label(frame_bottom, bg='#F59C60', text='Full Name:')
username_label.pack(pady=10)
```

Comment: Why do you call `return output` in the for loop? And those variables created after the for loop are then meaningless.